# Lookup formula for multiple results not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

My dataset range is A2:B15. A2 & B2 has headers, Salesmanname & Product. Column A has Name in Duplicate.

Filter area is D2:G6. Row 2 has headers. Name & products.

From D3:D6 unique Salesman names are written.

In E3 I'm using this formula, which is returns Blank instead of results.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$13, SMALL(IF($D3=$A$3:$A$13, ROW($B$3:$B$13)-2,""), COLUMN()-4)),"")
```

Check out the formula for the fault. 
Thanks.

Comment: It is an array formula you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter and kindly show some Data to check what should be the result

Comment: @Sam,, YES I know IT'S an Array formula,, & I've executed with relevant keys also.
 
As I've written previously Column D has Name of sales person & in Col E, F & G their sales data should be reflected. 
Like D3:D6 has 

Ravi 
Soma
Dev
Hari 

From E3:E6 has sales data 
TV
CALC
TAB
COMPUTER

and similar values in F3:G6

Comment: where is your formula in column F

Comment: @Sam,, apply yourself the formula is written in E3 and will drag right up to the G3,, then drag down,, so formula will populate results in E3:G6. 

Hope this help you to understand,, ☺

Comment: This seems to work correctly for me.  The only blank value I get is in G6, and that gets corrected if the A & B ranges are extended to row 14.

Comment: Finally I got the solution,, posting the correct version of the Formula. 


{=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B, SMALL(IF($D3=$A$3:$A$13, ROW($B$3:$B$13), ""), COLUMN()-4)),"")


NB: Since I don't have required credit points so that unable to post as ANSWER.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the comments of OP by @RajeshS

> Finally I got the solution,, posting the correct version of the Formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B, SMALL(IF($D3=$A$3:$A$13, ROW($B$3:$B$13), ""), COLUMN()-4)),"")
```